# ControlsRendering and operating systems

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

Controls, such as those appearing in `Manipulate` constructs, are by default rendered depending on the operating system. Wrapping everything in `Style[..., ControlsRendering->"Generic"]` makes sure that the controls' appearance is independent of the operating system (right?).

My question now is split into three parts:

1. Does the rendering depend on the version of Mathematica es well? Specifically, is there a difference between versions 7, 8 and 9?
2. Is there a way to estimate how the controls will be rendered for another operating system? I.e. can I get a rough idea (I'm using Windows 7) how my `Manipulate` will look like on a machine with, e.g., Mac OS X 10.7? It would be enough for me to find out if any of the sizes of things like `Slider2D` or `SetterBar` objects change drastically. Does the `ImageSize` option for `Slider2D` ensure a consistent size even on different operating systems?
3. Can one define a function that makes sure that the default rendering is used on machines with windows, and the `"Generic"` style is used for non-Windows computers?

Answer (score 3):

For 1. and 2., all I can say is that I did not notice any change (the generic style is used when exporting to Flash or PDF) and that I don't think you can find out what a control will look like without trying it on a different OS.

For 3., you can use

```
ControlsRendering -> Dynamic@If[$OperatingSystem === "Windows", Automatic, "Generic"]
```

The `Dynamic` will make sure that this will not be evaluated only once when you create the control, but will stay "inlined" in the notebook and will be re-run every time you open it.

---

(To avoid confusion, note that the syntax `option -> Dynamic[...]` will only work in a few places, and only in expressions which are handled by the front end, such as graphics, styling and controls.  It won't work in a kernel function like `FindRoot` which is *executed*/*evaluated* as opposed to being just displayed like `Style` is.)

Answer (score 3):

For #1. The appearance of the controls is set by the code in the file

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "TextResources", "Controls.tr"}]
```

So if you have V7, 8, 9 **make copies** of that file and then cut and paste the code into a notebook and evaluate and see what the graphics look like.

[image]

For #2. I think the answer for #1 covers #2 as well.

For #3. @Szabolcs has answered this.

Comment: So the things accessible with `FrontEndResource` are all in the `.tr` files?

Comment: Yes -- lots of interesting things in there, but be careful making changes. I'm sure Wolfram would say *never* make changes.